# How to map views url to blog url

Tags: 7, views, theming, uri, nodes

In my site I am using blogs module. When I used `sitename/blog` default blog page will display. But my requirement is, I have created a view to display the blogs, this is on the path of `sitename/blog-display`. I want to display this view when i type the url `sitename/blog`. please suggest me how can I solve this. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom module with this code:

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items)
{
  $items['blog']['page callback'] = "MYMODULE_blog_replace";
  $items['blog']['file'] = "MYMODULE.module";
  $items['blog']['module'] = "MYMODULE";
}

function MYMODULE_blog_replace()
{
  return views_embed_view('VIEWMACHINENAME', 'default');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you solution, it seems working. But the css is not loading.for views templates i have written css in style.css and this  is in the theme folder. So i need to do add in this module or what??

Comment: No. CSS in styles.css will load for all frontend pages. Perhaps because you are now embedding the view a CSS selector you previously targeted is no longer available. Just debug the CSS, working from the top level selectors downwards.

Comment: May I know how can I get the content : Link field in template file. I tried by using this $row->field_field_news_link[0]['rendered']['#markup'] but no results came..